# How to add something to head for each remix route same as <Links> or <Meta> in remix

Tags: remix.run

I need to add some *inline css* or *css variables* to the head for each remix route.

but it seems impossible because the root.jsx component runs before _index.jsx component.

Can I still do this the same way as Links or Meta is working?

I tried to do it using a singleton but I was unsuccessful. Example:

```js
// src/routeData.js
let routeData = {};

export function setRouteData(key, value) {
   routeData[key] = value;
}
    
export function getRouteData(key) {
  if(key == null)
  {
    return routeData;
  }
    
 return routeData[key];
}
```

Then, in route loader function of *_index.tsx* I set the data:

```js
// _index.jsx
export async function loader({ request, params }) {
   ...some logic
    
   setRouteData('bodyClass', bodyClass);
   setRouteData('cssConfig', cssConfig);
   setRouteData('cssVars', cssVars);
   ... etc
    }
```

Last, I would want use that in *root.tsx*:

```js
// root.tsx
export default function App() {
   const routeData = setRouteData();
}
```

Can I do something like this? I don't understand how Meta or Links are working under the hood. but I thought something like this be done the same way as Meta or Links.

Comment: This might be useful - https://github.com/remix-run/examples/blob/main/dark-mode/app/root.tsx